# Understanding example of product topology

Tags: general-topology

According to the book, I am reading, product topology on space $X=\prod_{\alpha\in\Omega}X_\alpha$ is the weak topology generated by $\{\pi_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\Omega}$ where $\pi_\alpha$ is the coordinate map from $X$ to $X_\alpha$. I consider some examples where $X_1=X_2=\{a,b,c\}$ where their corresponding topologies are $\mathcal{T_1}=\mathcal{T}_2=\{\emptyset,X_{i},\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. Take $X_1\times X_2$, then take $\mathcal{E}=\{\emptyset,\pi^{-1}_1(\{a\}),\pi^{-1}_1(\{a,b\}),\cdots\}$, where $\pi^{-1}_1(\{a\})=\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c)\},\pi^{-1}_1(\{a,b\})=\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c)\}$. Now the product topology is basically the topology generated by $\mathcal{E}$.(i.e. includes arbitrary union of finite intersections of members of $\mathcal{E}$)

Then later in the book, it says something about the product topology on the space of complex valued functions $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{R}}$, where I am totally lost in trying to see what the product topology looks like on this space, and also what is the product here $X_1=\mathbb{R},X_2=\mathbb{C}$? Can someone try to help me piece out the product topology on here? Thanks

Comment: $\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}\neq\mathbb C\times\mathbb R$. Here let $\mathbb C_a$ be a copy of the complex numbers for any $a\in\mathbb R$. Then $\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}=\prod_{a\in\mathbb R}\mathbb C_a$. This is the product of uncountably many items, so it's not very intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware that we can write $\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}=\prod_{r\in\mathbb R}\mathbb C_r$ where $\mathbb C_r=\mathbb C$ for every $r\in\mathbb R$.

Every element of $\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}$ corresponds with a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$.

In this setting projection $\pi_r:\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}\to\mathbb C$ is prescribed by $f\mapsto f(r)$.

This makes it clear that actually:$$\pi_r^{-1}(U)=\{f\in\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}\mid f(r)\in U\}$$for $r\in\mathbb R$ and $U\subseteq\mathbb C$.

So a subbase for the topology on $\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}$ is the collection of sets of form $\{f\in\mathbb C^{\mathbb R}\mid f(r)\in U\}$ where $r\in\mathbb R$ and $U\subseteq\mathbb C$ is an open set.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots that can be said about the [product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#:%7E:text=The%20product%20topology%2C%20sometimes%20called,is%20called%20the%20product%20space.),  or Tychonoff, topology (one is that the Tychonoff theorem applies,  saying that the product of compact spaces is compact).

I will just add a couple things to the accepted answer.   For an infinite product like $\Bbb C^\Bbb R$, it winds up consisting in arbitrary unions of sets of the form $\prod_{i\in\Bbb R} U_i $,  where each $U_i$ is open in
$\Bbb C$, and  $U_i=\Bbb C$ for all but finitely many $i\in\Bbb R$.  That's such sets *generate* the product topology.

One more note, the product topology is also called the *topology of pointwise convergence*,  because a sequence (or net) in $\prod_{i\in\Bbb R}\Bbb C$ converges if and only if each of its projections converges in $\Bbb C$.